# How to remove extra whitespace above a UITableView?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I'm have been trying to get the header of the table scrolling along with the `UITableView`. It's finally working, however, now there's **a whitespace showing up right under the map view** (see screenshot). I had difficulty getting the map in the table header section to scroll with the table and also to get the UIButton to trigger within the table header with a user touch (the UIButton simply expands the map to full screen.).

I asked a question related to this yesterday regarding the scrolling and button touch. Those are working now - I'm sure the coding could be done better, but this is what I have at the moment and have to get this done asap. If I can resolve this whitespace issue I can refactor and optimize the code later.

thanks for any help with this.

notice the whitespace under the map and above the table view in the screenshot - I want to bring the table view so it's close to the map.

[image]

in my `viewDidLoad`: method

```
  // mapview
    self.topMapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 140)];

    self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.height,self.view.frame.size.height)];

    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    self.tableView.delegate = self;

    self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];
```

then in the `viewForHeaderInSection:` method (It was suggested that this be done in the `viewDidLoad:` method and I tried that but it gave me more problems

```
   - (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 320, 140)];         
    UIButton *showMapButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    showMapButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0, 320.0, 140.0); 
    [showMapButton setTitle:@"show map" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [showMapButton addTarget:self
                     action:@selector(mapDetailViewDisplay:)
           forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

    [headerView addSubview:self.topMapView];
    [headerView showMapButton];

    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView;

    return headerView;
    }

    - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
        return 140;
    }
```

Comment: It looks like you are having that white line between every cell. I would recommend setting your cell separator style to none. `self.yourTableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;`

Comment: @Priyatham51 it's not the whiteline between the table cells, but the large space (I guess it's grey) between the map and the table. thanks :)

Comment: i guess that is section/table header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to move all code in `- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section` leaving only `return headerView`

in `viewDidLoad`

and change

```
UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] init];
```

instead of

```
UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 320, 140)];
```

Comment: it was this line: UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 320, 140)]; I changed it to:
UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] init];  and it worked great! thanks!!!

Answer (score 6):

Just add this in you ViewDidLoad method

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

Answer (score 2):

`[UITableView tableHeaderView]` is something different than `viewForHeaderInSection` but you are setting the same object to both of them.

You should rather set `self.tableView.tableHeaderView` in `viewDidLoad:` or return a headerView through viewForHeaderInSection delegate method depending on what kind of behaviour you are trying to achieve.